# Centos 6.8 failed reboot dedicated server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, partition, boot, grub

Ok so I bought/rent a dedicated server from nocix with Centos 6.8 installed, also came with 2 hard drives `sda - 128GB SSD` & `sdb - 2TB HDD` and I think I made a mistake by partitioning the second drive /dev/sdb and then reboot but lost the ability to connect via SSH, so I contacted nocix and they said I had to reload with the SystemRescueCd.

So I did that and have been reading/following the steps outlined here: https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Sysresccd-Partitioning-EN-Repairing-a-damaged-Grub

See below error messages I got when I ran `grub-install /dev/sda`

df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
Could not find device for /boot: Not found or not a block device.

See my partitions below. I've got 2 drives sda and sdb.

```
[=====DEVICE=====] [==FILESYS==] [======LABEL======] [====SIZE====] [MAJ] [MIN]
[loop0           ] [squashfs   ] [<unknown>        ] [   275.14 MB] [  7] [  0]
[sda1            ] [ext2       ] [<unknown>        ] [   250.00 MB] [  8] [  1]
[sda2            ] [LVM2_member] [<unknown>        ] [   119.00 GB] [  8] [  2]
[sdb1            ] [ext3       ] [/userdata        ] [     1.82 TB] [  8] [ 17]
[dm-0            ] [ext4       ] [<unknown>        ] [   110.25 GB] [253] [  0]
[dm-1            ] [ext4       ] [<unknown>        ] [     1.00 GB] [253] [  1]
[dm-2            ] [swap       ] [<unknown>        ] [     7.72 GB] [253] [  2]
```

I did see there is another guide about restoring on LVM and then noticed I have an LVM drive.. I am very new to this so I'm not sure what to do.. It's also quite urgent as the websites this server is hosting are down because of I can't get it back online.

EDIT: Output of `vgscan`

```
WARNING: lvmetad is running but disabled. Restart lvmetad before enabling it!
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "vg" using metadata type lvm2
```

And output of `lvscan`

```
  WARNING: lvmetad is running but disabled. Restart lvmetad before enabling it!
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg/root' [110.25 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg/tmp' [1.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg/swap' [7.72 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Please add the output of `vgscan` and `lvscan` to your question.

Comment: Anybody? I really need help

Comment: Forget the rescue CD, just boot normally and login at the (remote) console. Or, at least, look at the remote console to find out if it's not booting and why.

Comment: What is the remote console? (sorry I am very new)

Comment: I just googled it, do you mean physical access to the server? Because its 5000 miles from me, this is a hosted dedicated server and I only have ssh access with putty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to figure it out!

When I first tried reinstalling grub I thought that `/root` was on a partition called `/dev/loop0` and was mounting that.

Then I learned that my system is using LVM and then mounted `/dev/vg/root` to do the reinstall and it worked! Server rebooted as if nothing happened! It was down for more than 24 hours..